# Replace div's content with hidden content from a dynamic list

Tags: jquery

I've got a list of clickable images each with a hidden dl and relative content:

```
<div class="thumbs">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="tom" />
            <dl style="display: none;">
                <dd>Content 1</dd>
                <dd>Content 1</dd>
                <dd>Content1 </dd>
            </dl>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="dick" />
            <dl style="display: none;">
                <dd>Content 2</dd>
                <dd>Content 2</dd>
                <dd>Content 2</dd>
            </dl>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="harry" />
            <dl style="display: none;">
                <dd>Content 3</dd>
                <dd>Content 3</dd>
                <dd>Content 3</dd>
            </dl>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="panel">
<ul>
    <li>Content X</li>
    <li>Content X</li>
    <li>Content X</li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

For each image that is clicked, I want to take its adjacent dl content and use it to replace the ul content in .panel div. An initial stab resulted in:

```
  $('.thumbs').delegate("img", "click", function(){
    $('.thumbs dl').each(function(idx) {
    $('.panel ul').html($(this));
    return false;
    });
  });
```

But this replaces the .panel's content incrementally, beginning with the first dl's content (tom) – disregarding which img element was actually clicked. I want to be able to click on any image, in any order and replace the panel's content with that image's relative dl.

Comment: Does it need to become a `ul`? If it does, shouldn't it be a `ul` in the first place?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a `ul` in the .panel. Also I'm steering clear of using a nested `ul` in the thumbs `div` because I've got a couple of other plugins that are using the that tag as a hook. Hence the weirdly nested `dl`.

Comment: @Seb- have you got your solution?

Comment: Yes we have a winner. Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the structure will always be as you have shown in your example, the following would work:

```
$('.thumbs').delegate("img", "click", function(){
    $('.panel ul').html($(this).next().html());
});
```

The problem with your initial attempt is that you are looping through all `dl` elements within `.thumbs`, and you don't try to find only the relevant `dl`.

The solution above uses the `next` method to get the next element in the DOM to the one that was clicked (which will always be the `dl` in your example), and replaces the HTML of `.panel ul` with the HTML of that `dl`.

Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/aASuA/2/).

If the structure could change, so the `dl` element doesn't come directly after the `img`, you can replace the line inside the `delegate` function with this:

```
$('.panel ul').html($(this).parent().find("dl").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
$('.thumbs').delegate("img", "click", function(){
     $('.panel ul').html(this.find('dl').html());
    return false;
    });
  });
```